# Make files in web server match a certain git commit

Tags: git

I am trying to set up my web server to download a particular version of the website.  Basically all I need on the server is to be able to issue a command that will make the folder match that commit.

I've tried searching for this, but it seems there is LOTS of info on git, and many different answers.  So I'm not sure what the answer is, or what the CORRECT answer is.

This is what I find to work, but it's seems a bit convoluted.

```
git fetch origin
git checkout {hash}
git pull
```

Is there a better way?  And will this work in all situations (state of repo, etc)?

To clarify I don't need to make any commits on the web server, it only needs to receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git reset --hard` to put your working directory into the exact state of a commit. I generally do the following on server when deploying a version (usually automated):

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

This will overwrite all tracked files with the version from the just fetched `origin/master`.

Note that this does not remove untracked or ignored files. If you need to do that, you need to run [`git clean`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) afterwards:

```
git clean -xdf
```

Comment: When I try `git reset --hard origin/{commit-hash}` I get "unknown revision or path not in the working tree"

Comment: @Sarke I didn’t say `origin/{commit-hash}`, I said `origin/master`…

Comment: I know, but my question is how to get a specific commit, not just master.  Does your answer work for that?

Comment: You can use `git reset --hard {commit}`; but the idea behind my solution is to fetch the latest version from `origin` and then use that version (without having to know its commit id).

Comment: Thank you, that works.  I get the commit ID through a API call, so that's not a problem.